# Truffle Develop Could not find suitable configuration file

Tags: contract-development, metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp, truffle-develop

Basically, after I installed the truffle the command: nom truffle -g . Then I went to set up the metamask on the google chrome. Once the metamask is set up then I try the command: truffle develop and I get this:  Could not find suitable configuration file. 
Any suggestions ? Please Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You need to initialize an empty directory with `truffle init`. But If you are just starting it is better to start from a tutorial like @SurbhiAudichya is pointing that already have the correct configuration.

Answer (score 1):

https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop
to find out all dependencies to use truffle and metamask.

Answer (score 0):

There could be few reason to this
1. Either you would have somehow mistakenly deleted the package.json or package-lock.json ( In my case it was package-lock.json) .So try to do "npm i" in order to install all the necessary packages, then try again.
2. Do check if you have truffle-config.js

Answer (score 0):

This post is hidden. You deleted this post just now.

I resolved this issue by running init @ the CMD prompt - 'truffle init'

if all goes well you may have a prompt Init successful, sweet!